# Connect Android SIP to OfficeSip server

Tags: android, sip

I am developing an Android SIP client. I'd like to test it against OfficeSip server. So I have set up the officeSip server locally and I can connect to it via officeSIP messenger (the client).

The messenger requires this data to login:

- List item
- addr: username@server_domain
- username: username
- password: password
- protocol: protocol
- server address: server address

However, when trying to do the same in Android, its [SipProfile.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipProfile.Builder.html#setOutboundProxy%28java.lang.String%29) has a bit different parameters. Of note are the following:

```
public SipProfile.Builder (String username, String serverDomain)
public SipProfile.Builder setOutboundProxy (String outboundProxy)
```

There doesn't seem to be a server address available.

I have tried the following for serverDomain parameter:

- user@server_domain/server_ip
- server_domain/server_ip
- server_domain@server_ip
- many other combinations

However, I'm either getting *connection error* (when @ is used) or *registration failed* event (when / is used with server IP after the /). Error codes are -4 (When some error occurs on the device, possibly due to a bug) first, immediately followed by -9 (The client is in a transaction and cannot initiate a new one)

How can I connect to OfficeSIP using Android SIP client?

**Edit:**
I managed to establish communication with [CSipSimpleClient](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) which uses a custom SIP stack. It only required server name (equal to server's domain), username and password.

Comment: Hi I was on the same issue currently can you please help me how to come out of it , i have read below answer ,i felt make my question clear i have commented here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Android SIP stack is quite immature and finnicky.

Ultimately I was able to connect by specifying both server hostname and server proxy.
Also, if server domain differs from computer name server is running on, you WILL have issues connecting. Domain must match either IP address or computer name, but they must match in order to connect via Android SIP client.

Comment: velis> I am trying to use the CSipSimple Android SIP client to connect to OfficeSIP server, using user, password, and server (ip address) - basic wizard. It just fails to register the user with message 'Request Timeout'

Comment: Are you even running the server? If so, you need to specify the correct IP address.

Comment: Yes i am running the server, and i can connect successfully from OfficeSIP Messenger app, running on the same machine as the server (not tried remote yet, as i do not have spare machine right now). I also checked from Android Device Command Line that IP Address and the port are indeed reachable from android device. I wonder what else to look into.

Comment: Does OfficeSIP server domain match its name as you are trying to access it? If you're using IP, domain name must be IP, if you're using machine name, domain must match that.

Comment: If it doesn't match, you have to write server address as domain@ip - if I remember correctly.

Comment: @veils, In OfficeSIP Server > Settings i see SIP Domain Name - it is set to officesip.local, i have tried with this as well as putting IP but it does not work. I am on a wifi network, i guess SIP Client needs the windows domain name of SIP machine itself etc? I guess i shud create a new question for this.

Comment: You might. First try entering officesip.local/machine_name or officesip.local@machine_name (the format is actually written on the same form at the top) in server address field though.

Comment: Hi guys , i have configured officesip server and messenger and working from wifi domain all works fine for me , but my problem is with android given code android sip demo app latest one how to pass my parameters according to officesip server can you guys tell how to solve this below is the app i was using, https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SipDemo

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure.. but '@' and '/' are not allowed and SipProfile.Builder will make a URI, e.g. "username@serverDomain(or ip)", with username and serverDomain parameters.
Just try to set like this.. ("user1", "test.com"), ("user1", "1.1.1.1").

API description says "the SIP server domain; if the network address is different from the domain, use setOutboundProxy(String) to set server address" about serverDomain.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully connected to OfficeSIP with the android SIP API.

1. Download the SipDemo [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SipDemo/)
2. In WalkieTalkieActivity.java I modified the code to be the following:

   SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("test", "officesip.local");

   builder.setPassword("test");

   builder.setOutboundProxy("192.168.10.191");

   builder.setAutoRegistration(true);

   me = builder.build();
3. In OfficeSIP test is the user with a password also test.  The outbound proxy is the IP of the computer or server hosting OfficeSIP and officesip.local is the SIP domain name, which can be found in OfficeSIP under ther settings tab.
4. To test this I made a second account on OfficeSIP and logged into that account using Sipdroid.  From there I called the SipDemo app running on a second phone and it worked.

Comment: I experience issue with this. The SIP messenger shows one account is in 'Connected' state, but another one is in "Connecting" state. The last one is linked to WalkieTalkie demo app and status of mobile client is "Ready". Did you have similar experience on this? Do you have any clue on cause behind it?